# Reordering Datasets in Multidimensional-List with less read/write Effort

Tags: c#, frameworks, logic, entity

For first, it's my first Question in here. If something is unclear please simply ask!

I want to Reorder a "current" List with a "target" List. 
So far so good, but because it is on a Database I like to do this with as less effort as possible. 
First, take some (Pseudo-)Models and (Pseudo-)Algorithms.

First the Shelf

```
public class Shelf
{
    public Int64 ShelfID { get; set; }
}
```

Second the Shelfrack

```
public class Rack 
{
   public Int64 RackID { get; set; }       

   public Int64 ShelfID { get; set; }
   public virtual Shelf Shelf { get; set; } 
}
```

Third the Book

```
public class Book
{
   public Int64 BookID { get; set; }

   public Int64 RackID { get; set; }
   public virtual Rack Rack { get; set; }

   public Int64? PreviousBookID { get; set; } // No virtual here
   public Int64? NextBookID { get; set; } // No virtual here too
}
```

The Lists

```
List<Tuple<Shelf, List<Tuple<Rack, List<Book>>>>> bookListByShelfCurrent = GetBookListCurrent();
List<Tuple<Shelf, List<Tuple<Rack, List<Book>>>>> bookListByShelfTarget = GetBookListTarget();
```

What I like now to do is order the CurrentList to the Target-List where the Target List is the Reference.

- If the content is the same, I like to skip the object
- If the content is not the same, I like to reorder.
- If the Content is new, I like to add at the right place. (before, middle, after some Datasets)
- If the Content can't be found, I like to simply delete

Because I have to Reorder the Datasets within the Database I am not sure how to start. The Previous and Next-Logic is a Problem for me too. 
The database is experimentel but I can use Entity Framework for it.

Maybe one of you got a similiar Problem to?